# Rails datatables colviz getting Cannot read property 'msie'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I'm using the gem 'jquery-datatables-rails' in a Rails app.  I'm also using the ColViz tool.

But, I'm getting this error in the browser console when I use ColViz:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

This is my coffee script:

```
  $(".dataTable").dataTable
  bStateSave: true
  fnStateSave: (oSettings, oData) ->
   localStorage.setItem "DataTables_" + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData)

  fnStateLoad: (oSettings) ->
    JSON.parse localStorage.getItem("DataTables_" + window.location.pathname)

sDom: "CT<\"clear\">lfrtip"
oColVis:
  buttonText: "Show/Hide"
  aiExclude: [0]
  bRestore: true
  sAlign: "left"

oTableTools:
  aButtons: [
    sExtends: "xls"
    sButtonText: "Excel"
    mColumns: "visible"
  ,
    sExtends: "pdf"
    sPdfOrientation: "landscape"
    sPdfMessage: "Endeavor"
    mColumns: "visible"
  ]
```

UDPATE1

This is where I'm getting the error:

```
    /* This results in a very small delay for the end user but it allows the animation to be
     * much smoother. If you don't want the animation, then the setTimeout can be removed
     */
    setTimeout( function () {
        $(nHidden).animate({"opacity": 1}, that.s.iOverlayFade);
        $(nBackground).animate({"opacity": 0.1}, that.s.iOverlayFade, 'linear', function () {
            /* In IE6 if you set the checked attribute of a hidden checkbox, then this is not visually
             * reflected. As such, we need to do it here, once it is visible. Unbelievable.
             */
            if ( jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == "6.0" )
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
            {
                that._fnDrawCallback();
            }
        });
    }, 10 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the new version of jquery doesn't support .browser

I added this to my app jquery.mb.browser.js

You can find it at this location:

```
https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.browser/archive/master.zip
```